# Can't drag and drop in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, drag-and-drop, desktop

It seems like Desktop Icons NG (DING)  is not instelled on my desktop. I can't drag and drop items from or in the desktop. When I try to install it manually it says something like:

> this is an extension enabled by your current mode. Can't be installed.

But it is not installed...

Even in the setting it is not showing up.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

A similar thing happened when i upgraded to 22.04 from 20.04.
I found a solution here on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369508/my-desktop-icons-disappeared-when-i-upgraded-to-ubuntu-21-10).
You have to install `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng` and `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`.

```bash
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
```

and

```bash
sudo  apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

I had to restart my system for changes to take effect.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This did not help me :-(

Comment: I'm having similar issues too as this didn't work using the latest Ubuntu version 22.04.2 LTS.